# convert string array (of byte values) to byte array

Tags: c#

So I am having an array of strings that contains **values** of bytes and I want to move them straight into byte array. How can I do that?

```
//for example
string read="0 1 0 0 0 255 255 255 255";
byte[] bytes=null;
 string[] splitted = read.Split(' ');
        for(int i=0;i<splitted.Count();i++)
        {
            int value = Int32.Parse(splitted[i]);
            bytes[i] = (byte)value;
        }
        problem = bytes;
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Please clarify how the strings contain values of byte

Comment: @roryap see update

Comment: It would be very helpful if you show a sample content of read

Comment: @SirRufo Each string contains a value (numerical) that is supposed to be in the array of bytes. For example, here is a short list of strings: string[]=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255], and I want my array of bytes look like byte[]=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and straight forward

```
string read = "0 1 0 0 0 255 255 255 255";
byte[] result = read
  .Split( ' ' ) // => string[] / IEnumerable<string>
  .Select( s => byte.Parse( s ) ) // => IEnumerable<byte>
  .ToArray(); // => byte[]
```